# extract strings from PDF with font size bigger than some value

Tags: pdf, extract

I've got some badly formatted PDF literature I need to digest. It has no index, and that makes very difficult to navigate the file.

How can I extract all Strings from a PDF, whose font size is bigger than some value e.g. 20px, and the page number, which is always at the same position?

With that information, I can create index on my own.

Comment: In which programming language, using which PDF library, do you want to implement that?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Java, php, javascript, swift.. all is good